# Generate XSD in case of Recursive Node

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

How do we generate XSD when we have recursive Nodes in XML? My case "Questions" Node will be included with in "Question" Node.

Below is my sample XML that I am working on

```
<Sections>
<Section>
    <SectionId>12</SectionId>
     <SectionName>test test</SectionName>
    <Questions>
        <Question>
            <Id>100</Id>
            <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>
            <Questions>
                <Question>
                    <Id>101</Id>
                    <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>
                    <Questions>
                        <Question>
                            <Id>102</Id>
                            <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>                
                        </Question>
                        <Question>
                            <Id>103</Id>
                            <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>
                        </Question>
                    </Questions>                
                </Question>
                <Question>
                    <Id>104</Id>
                    <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>
                </Question>
            </Questions>
        </Question>
        <Question>
        <Id>200</Id>
        <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>
        <Questions>
            <Question>
                <Id>201</Id>
                <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>                
            </Question>
            <Question>
                <Id>202</Id>
                <QuestionText>Sample Text</QuestionText>
            </Question>
        </Questions>
    </Question>
    </Questions>
</Section></Sections>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create an element by name and inside it, reference another element by name that has this element as its child. Perhaps an example that illustrates this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xs:element name="Questions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Question"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Question">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Id" />
                <xs:element name="QuestionText" />
                <xs:element ref="Questions" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When applied against your example XML, it validates successfully.

#### Update

Quite against the spirit of SO, but as a gesture to the asker, here's an update of above's schema that applies to the updated question text:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xs:element name="Sections">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Section"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Section">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SectionId"/>                
                <xs:element name="SectionName"/>                
                <xs:element ref="Questions"/>  
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Questions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Question"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Question">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Id" />
                <xs:element name="QuestionText" />
                <xs:element ref="Questions" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks Abei, I have updated my sample XML to add Parent Nodes called "Sections" & "Section" and its details. And i try to add that new oarent  Nodes in XSD that you have given but i am unable to make it work. Could you update me with new XSD?

Comment: @VInayK, this is quite against the idea of StackOverflow, you should not edit your question beyond the original meaning. Though you changed the structure only slightly (and I dare say, I do not see the problem, you just added two parents), and because it was a trivial change, I decided to go with it and update it. But please, for SO it is better to ask a new question. It'll help you, gives others the opportunity to give their view, and well, it is within SO's policy ;)

Comment: @VInayK PS: my guess is that you are not using an XSD-capable editor. There are many on the market, and they will allow you to simply drag and drop your schema together, and/or provide you with context-sensitive help.

Comment: I will make sure next time. And the solution that you gave works perfect. Is there any best tools that you can suggest me?

Comment: @VInayK, I prefer oxygen, but visual studio also works, or liquid XML. On the free side there's eclipse, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion.